# Pointers to a hypergeometric distribution simplification wheel I probably reinvented

Tags: probability, combinatorics

There are $n$ white balls and $3n$ black balls, and you must pair all of them at random. What's the (approximate) probability that no two white balls are paired?

So, I consider that I start pairing all white balls first. The probability that it doesn't pair with another white ball is 3n/4n. For each subsequent white ball, there'll be one less black ball and two less total balls, which gives the following product as the odds to not pair any white balls:

$$p = \prod_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac {3n-i}{4n-2i}$$

To get an approximate answer, I took the log of both sides:

\begin{align}
  \log p \approx \sum_{i=0}^n \log \left( \frac{3n - i}{4n - 2i} \right) 
    &= \sum_{i=0}^n \log \left( \frac{3 - i/n}{4 - 2i/n} \right) \\
    &= \sum \log (3 - i/n) - \log (4 - 2i/n)
\end{align}

and "linearized" $\log(a - bi/n)$ as follows:

\begin{equation}
  \log(a - bi/n) \approx \frac1n ((n - i) \log a + i \log (a-b))
\end{equation}

This brings me to:

\begin{align}
  \log p &\approx \frac1n \left[ \sum (n-i)(\log 3 - \log 4) + i (\log 2 - \log 2) \right] \\
         &= \frac1n (\log 3 - \log 4) \sum (n - i) \\
         &= \frac1n (\log 3 - \log 4) \sum i \\
         &= - \frac12 (n-1) (\log 4 - \log 3)
\end{align}

So,

\begin{equation}
  p \approx \exp (-n/2 (\log 4 - \log 3))
\end{equation}

I believe this "linearization" is warranted only because 3 is close to 4, not sure if can be extended to any numbers. In the end, I got that $p \approx \exp (-0.14n)$.

Does this type of simplification already exists? Does this have a name?

Context: I'm considering what are the odds that a random graph generated by the configuration model from a tree is disconnected, ie, two leaves (white balls) connect to each other and not to the larger tree.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach to the problem is to consider the drawing of all $4n$ as "arrangements" and to count (a) the total number of arrangements, versus (b) those arrangements that give no white pair.

To count total arrangements is to count the number of ways to choose $n$ positions for the white balls from $4n$ positions available. This is just $\binom{4n}{n}$.

For any arrangement with no white pair, there are exactly $n$ pairs with $1$ white ball (and $1$ black ball). So we want the number of ways to select $n$ pairs for our $n$ white balls from the $2n$ pairs available. This is just $\binom{2n}{n}$. Now, for each of the $n$ black-white pairs. the two balls can be ordered in $2$ ways: white-black and black-white. So we must multiply our count by $2^n$, giving our count of no-white-pair arrangements as $\binom{2n}{n}2^n$.

Therefore,

$$P(\text{No white pair}) = \dfrac{\binom{2n}{n}2^n}{\binom{4n}{n}}.$$

Comment: Thanks for this approach, I skipped learning combinatorics and now I feel this gap. Following your derivation and using Stirling's approximation I got $p \approx \exp((3\log2+3\log3-4\log4)n) = \exp(-0.074n)$. I'll revise my calculations and see why they differ, but it's at least on the same order of magnitude (I'm an engineer, if this is not apparent).

Comment: @BrunoKim I think the probability of the first white ball not matching is $3n/(4n-1)$ (the $-1$ is because the white ball itself shouldn't be counted). This gives,

$$p = \prod_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac {3n-i}{4n-2i-1}$$

With this, the change of upper limit from $n-1$ to $n$ will make a tiny difference now. I can't figure out how you get your linearisation formula, so I can't say how valid it is.

Comment: It's simply a line interpolating between $\log a$ (for $i=0$) and $\log (a - b)$ (for $i=n$).